# Need to convert string into number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a number 10,000.00 and I want to check if it is greater than 0.

```
function chkgrt(num)
{
    if(num>0){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

chkgrt('10,000.00')

It always returns `false`.
I wonder why it is returning `false` even though I have passed 10000 which is greater than 0.

Comment: `Chkgrt(10,000.00)` This will cause a syntax error

Comment: Why converting a readable `num > 0` into an obscure `chkgrt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your function as below

```
function chkgrt(num){
    num = num.replace(',',"");
    if(num > 0){
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Always pass as string

Answer (score 2):

Following gives me false since you are checking a string against 0

```
chkgrt('10,000.00')
false
```

I parse it into float as you have .00 in it, then it works

```
chkgrt(parseFloat('10,000.00'.replace(',','')))
true
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how are you passing the number. If you are passing 10000 or 10000.00 to your `chkgrt()` function it will return true.
But if you pass 10,000.00 it will return a syntax error. In order to pass 10,000.00 as the number in your function you need to parse your input using the following code  :

```
var newNum = num.replace(',', '');
```